# Aplicar un Guard en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, guardar

necesito proteger la ruta "/completo", la ruta se debe mostrar despues de hacer un login (el cual se hace si el token es correcto) el Guard que necesito debe verificar que los datos de mis inputs que se obtienen de mi API y se muestran en mi pagina "/persona" tengan correctas sus validaciones, y que los campos requeridos esten completos, si algun campo esta faltante, se me enviara al formulario "/persona" para completarlo, de lo contrario, si el Guard no encuentra ningun error, debe enviarme a "/completo", de igual manera, si esta mal una validacion, se me enviara a "/persona" para corregirlo, de igual manera, si esta mal una validacion, se me enviara a /persona para corregirlo

Lo que tengo entendido es que debo encontrar la lógica para saber a quien si y a quien no mostrarle el formulario, a partir de los datos que ya esten almacenados, pero esto lo debo realizar con un Guard, y es lo que me causa conflicto.

de esta manera hago el login

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  correoElectronico!: string;
  clavePrivada!: string;
  idAplicacion!: string;
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  login() {
    const url = 'miRuta';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-client-id': 'miToken.'
    });

    const hashedClavePrivada = sha256(this.clavePrivada);
    const body = {
      correo_electronico: this.correoElectronico,
      clave_privada: hashedClavePrivada,
    };

    this.http.post(url, body, { headers }).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem('token', (response as any)['X_TOKEN_ACCOUNT']);
        this.router.navigate(['/persona']);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

  private buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      correoElectronico: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      clavePrivada: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

este es el guardian de mi login

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

en mi app-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'persona', component: PersonaComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'completo', component: CompletoComponent }
];
```

algunas de mis validaciones, y tambien se ven cuales son las que son requeridas:

```
 private buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i), Validators.required]],
      primer_apellido: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i), Validators.required]],
      segundo_apellido: ['', Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1 ]*$/i)],
      clave_privada: ['', Validators.required],
      nuevaclave: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]).*$/)]],
      nuevaclave_confirmar: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]).*$/)]],
    }, {
      validators: this.passwordsMatchValidator
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.formValid = this.form.valid;
    });
  }
```

y no se si sirva, pero de esta manera obtengo los datos de mi API y los muestro en los campos correspondientes en mi formulario

```
async getUserData() {
    try {
      this.userData = await this.userService.getUserData();
      if (this.userData && this.userData.persona) {
        this.form.patchValue({
          nombre: this.userData.persona.nombre,
          primer_apellido: this.userData.persona.primer_apellido,
          segundo_apellido: this.userData.persona.segundo_apellido,
        });
      }

      console.log('this.userData2', this.userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

la pagina "/completo" solo lo uso como ejemplo, debido a que me dijeron que esa pagina va a variar dependiendo de que tipo de usuario inicie sesión, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: La request Http y el hash de los datos de login deberían estar un servicio, no en el componente.